# Delegate function in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-plugins

This function applies to my html array.
Just a question, how to delegate this for the lines that will dynamically insert with ajax.

```
    $('#mytable').bootstrapTable({
  contextMenu: '#context-menu',
  onContextMenuItem: function (row, $el) {
      if ($el.data("item") == "add") {
      alert('It work');
      }
      if ($el.data("item") == "edit") {
      alert('It work');
      }
      if ($el.data("item") == "delete") {
      alert('It work');
      }
  }
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: There's no way, AFAIK. You need to initialize the plugin manually on the HTML added using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to do it with ajax?

Comment: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/es/documentation/ , ajaxOptions ?